# [Cucumber]Ruby constants strange behavior

Tags: ruby, cucumber, constants

I found pretty strange behavior that I can't explain by myself. Looks like if u use Cucumber and Constants at the same time Ruby will save local variables between Scenarios.
In Cucumber test.feature file I have steps like this

```
    Feature: Test

  Scenario Outline: Test outline
    Given Set data
      |user_id  |hash  |
      |<user_id>|<hash>|

    Examples:
      |user_id|hash|
      |king   |xfgh|

  Scenario Outline: What is going on
    Given Set data
      |shop_id|
      |<shop_id>|

    Examples:
      |shop_id|
      |554    |
```

Than I have steps.rb file like this:

```
   Given(/^Set data$/) do |table|
  # table is a table.hashes.keys # => [:smth]
  temp = Constants::Cons.dup
  table.hashes[0].each do |key, values|
    temp[:bodyData][eval(":#{key}")] = values
  end
  puts("temp: #{temp}")
end
```

file cmodule.rb:

```
module Constants

 Cons =
 {
     :toService => "Microcontrol",
     :bodyData=>{}
 }

end
```

And file env.rb:

```
require_relative 'cmodule'
World(Constants)
```

So, than I run file test.feature my output looks like this:

```
temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:user_id=>"king", :hash=>"xfgh"}}

temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:user_id=>"king", :hash=>"xfgh", :shop_id=>"554"}}
```

So, the question is, why is my second Scenario Outline gives output like this:

```
temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:user_id=>"king", :hash=>"xfgh", :shop_id=>"554"}}
```

And not like this (that's what I've expected from scenario to do at first):

```
temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:shop_id=>"554"}}
```

But there's more, I've started an experiment and changed my cmodule.rb to:

```
module Constants
 def self.cons
   {
       :toService => "Microcontrol",
       :bodyData=>{}
   }
 end

end
```

Also changed steps.rb:

```
Given(/^Set data$/) do |table|
  # table is a table.hashes.keys # => [:smth]
  temp = Constants.cons.dup
  table.hashes[0].each do |key, values|
    temp[:bodyData][eval(":#{key}")] = values
  end
  puts("temp: #{temp}")
end
```

After running test.feature I've got:

```
temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:user_id=>"king", :hash=>"xfgh"}}

temp: {:toService=>"Microcontrol", :bodyData=>{:shop_id=>"554"}}
```

So, I'cant figure out why does it work with def and doesn't work with Constants?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you debug in your step definitions and examine self you can find out the answer. The following is speculation:

When you add a module to World this means that the contents of that module are available to every step definitions, because inside a step definition self is World. When you define a `Cons` as a constant you set a value that is designed to not be able to be changed. It lives for the life of the containing object. So `Cons` will be the same hash in every step definition (look at the object ids to confirm this). When you use def you are calling the method so you will be getting a different hash in every step definition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, another questions is:
As u can see I've used a `.dup` method, which copies value from constant. Also, while using `.dup` I printed `object_id` of each `temp` and ID was different every time. Why in this case it works the same?

Comment: Examine the object id's of the things in the duplicated structure and see if those are the same. My answer is about giving you the tools to work out whats going on, I can't offer more than that, it would take too much time, sorry.